# How do non-mechanical solid-state optical switches work?

Tags: optics, experimental-technique, fiber-optics, optical-materials, experimental-technology

I am currently looking for a fiber-optical switch (FOS) in order to be able to change the light source of a spectrometer. As this will be used in harsh conditions, I was hoping to find a FOS with no moving parts.

Today I came across [this](https://www.fiber-mart.com/2x1-solidstate-fiber-optic-switches-p-2934.html), which appears to be an optical fiber switch with no moving parts. Although I will not be able to use this switch due to the wavelength range not being a good fit, I was wondering how these kinds of switches work. So far, I have only seen optomechanical ones which I assume to use some sort of actuated mirror assembly to redirect the light from the correct input fibers to the output fiber. On a smaller scale, I have seen piezoelectric devices which just move the physical output fiber by a tiny amount left and right.

I have read somewhere about a magneto-optic crystals, which appear to be a crystal whose transmission is based on the voltage applied to it. Is this how such a switch could be implemented? Are there other ways?

Comment: you could also take a look at optical switches from thorlabs. I do not know how those switches are made.

Comment: This question is the subject of a [Meta discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13364/44126).

Comment: It says on the sheet that it is a magneto optical switch...

Comment: As a start, while the marketing blurb doesn't say much about the operation, it does say that the configuration is patented. This is good news -- all patents are public, and should be searchable.

Comment: In general I would not find such a device complicated to understand, but the switch says 2 things that are a bit incompatible for me: it latches with no power and it does not have movable parts. I would imagine that changing something to do with the faraday rotator without later on needing power means for example a rotation of a magnet. I could not yet find the patent for such a device (but I am looking).

Comment: Oh, ok, maybe they use liquid crystals and permanently align the molecules with the voltage, and then use the magneto-optical effect to switch it...? Although that sounds redundant without sketching the setup. But still searching for the patent, just saw another with liquid crystals and thought it could be a way.

Comment: @huhmonster Ok, I am sorry for the spamming, but found a paper which seems to point in the direction of this kind of switches: [quasi-passive latching switches](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6359294)

Comment: I may have time to write an answer later, but two ways this can be done is with [magnetically controlled polarization](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6577430) changes and with [bistable](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150355458A1/) [MEMS](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8203775B1/) mirrors ([image](https://photonwares.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/1xnmems2.png)). Lots of information by looking at the patents for [Agiltron](https://agiltron.com/category/fiber-optic-switches/mems-optical-switches-etmems/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like there are at least two ways to go about this:

## **Bistable MEMS**

[MEMS (Microelectromechanical systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems) are very small structures, with features from $1-100\mu m$ in size, generally made with semiconductor-like processes. They can be made so they are bistable, if you apply a pulse of power, their state will change and remain stable until another pulse of power is applied to change it back. Patent [US8203775B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8203775B1/) describes one of these structures used by [Agiltron for at least some of their 1xN and NxN optical switches](https://agiltron.com/category/fiber-optic-switches/mems-optical-switches-etmems/).

Here is the patent drawing of the two states the MEMS mirror can be in:

[image: US8203775B1 drawings]

Here is a diagram ([from Agiltron](https://agiltron.com/category/fiber-optic-switches/mems-optical-switches-etmems/mems-1xn-optical-switch/)) showing how they are used to form a 1xN switch:

[image: 1xN diagram]

## **Magneto-optic effect**

This can be achieved with materials that change the polarization of light like [bismuth-substituted rare earth iron garnet single crystal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0254058401003650) that depending on the polarity of the applied magnetic field, change the polarization by plus or minus 45 deg. The light will then either be blocked or transmitted by a static polarizer. A magnetic field applied to the rare earth iron garnet will magnetize it, so a continuous field is not required. You only need a pulse of power to change the polarity of the magnetization. Below is a diagram from patent [US6577430B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6577430) that shows the stack up inside a bidirectional 1x2 switch. I believe this technique is used in [Agiltron's CrystaLatch 1xN and NxN switches](https://agiltron.com/category/fiber-optic-switches/high-reliability-optical-switches-crystalatch/).

[image: US6577430B1 drawing]

Comment: Super interesting, I had no idea that "switchable" magnets existed. I just assumed they would have to move them mechanically to change the field. Although I didn't ask this question, I was definitely very curious about it, so, many thanks for this great answer.

Comment: Do bistable MEMS count as "no moving parts" as far as engineering goes?

Comment: Generally yes, they are small enough that "normal" issues with mechanical systems don't apply. People would say thay the accelerometers in your phone are solid state and not mechanical, even though they contain MEMS.